# ContentHandler is taking a lot of time to go through 3MB XML parsed xlsx file

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, sax

I'm using SAX parser and XSSFReader of apache.poi to parse .xlsx file. my sheet contains up to 650 columns and 2000 rows (file size- about 2.5 MB). my code looks like so:

```java
public class MyClass {
   public static void main(String path){
      try {
         OPCPackage pkg = OPCPachage.open(new FileInputStream(path));
         XSSFReader reader = new XSSFReader(pkg);
         InputStream sheetData = reader.getSheet("rId3"); //the needed sheet
         MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
         XMLReader parser = SAXHelper.newXMLReader();
         parser.setContentHandler(handler);
         parser.parse(new InputSource(sheetData));
      }
      catch (Exception e){
         //or other catches with required exceptions
      }
   }
}

class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
   @Override
   public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) {
      if("row".equals(name)) {
         System.out.pringln("row: " + attributes.getValue("r"));
      }
   }
}
```

but unfortunately I saw that it takes 2 or 3 seconds to go over one row, that means that going over the sheet takes over than 30 minutes(!!)
Well, I am sure this is not supposed to be, if it was- noboy was suggesing apache.poi eventaApi for large files, was he?

I want to get to the `<mergeCell>` values at the end of the XML (after the closing `</sheetData>`, is there a better way to do it? (I was thinking of handle with the string of the xml, and simply search with some regular expression for the required values, is it possible?)

So- I have two questions:
**1.** What's wrong with my code/why it takes so long? (when I think about it- it actually sounds as normal situation, 600 cells- why not processing in few seconds?)
**2.** Is there a way to treat XML as a text file and simply search in it using regex?

Comment: You're going to have to read up on how to use a Java profiler - this is how developers find the bottlenecks in their code. Lots of people use POI for streaming workbooks and they don't get 2 seconds per row performance.

Comment: that xlsx doesn't even sound big - you could consider using POI XSSFWorkbook which is simpler to use than the streaming APIs

Comment: You're right that there's something badly wrong here, unfortunately it's not apparent from the code you've shown us what this might be. If you were to post a complete repro (something we can run ourselves to see if we get the same result) then there's some chance we could help you.